# VS2008 - Can aspx inline reference 'Cannot resolve symbol...' should stop the build?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I'm looking for a way to mark a build as failed if an inline reference on an aspx page is invalid.

For example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="<%# Model.SomeText %>"></asp:TextBox>
```

If SomeText doesn't exist on Model I get the following message:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'SomeText'

However, the application builds just fine.  Is there any way to halt the build or mark it as failed when references such as this don't resolve?  I've tried *'Treat warnings as errors'*, but it doesn't seem to apply to aspxs (due to the fact that they're not compiled with the rest of the app).

Thanks!

Comment: My example didn't render... trying again...

Text="<%# Model.SomeText %>"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to put this into the build process itself, but have a look at [aspnet_compiler.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863%28VS.80%29.aspx).

```
aspnet_compiler -v /
```

The above command will compile your IIS root (and all files under it) and will show you any and all errors that you would normally have to wait until runtime to witness. It also means that all of your pages become precompiled so access times are reduced (for first load only)

Answer (score 0):

For the razor view engine (asp.net mvc) you can switch view compiling to on by editing the project file:

`<MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>` <- this is default. Set to true

Afaik there is nothing similar in Webforms. Refer to this other SO question:
['Is there an equivalent to MvcBuildViews for webforms?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628799/is-there-an-equivalent-to-mvcbuildviews-for-webforms)
A workaround using a postbuild action is proposed in the accepted answer.