# Is there an equivalent to MvcBuildViews for webforms?

Tags: webforms

Is there an equivalent to MvcBuildViews for webforms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no.

An alternative is to add a postbuild action to the visual studio project and have it run the [aspnet_compiler.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863.aspx) to "compile an application in place".

> Compiling an Application in Place
>
> The ASP.NET Compilation tool can
>   compile an application in place, that
>   is, it mimics the behavior of making
>   multiple requests to the application,
>   thus causing regular compilation.
>   Users of a precompiled site will not
>   experience a delay caused by compiling
>   the page on first request.
>
> Note that if you are using an
>   impersonated account, both the account
>   and the logon user account must have
>   write access to the target for
>   precompilation to succeed.
>
> When you precompile a site in place,
>   the following items apply:
>
> - The site retains its files and
>     directory structure.
> - You must have compilers for all
>     programming languages used by the site
>     on the server.
> - If any file fails compilation, the
>     entire site fails compilation.
>
> You can also recompile an application
>   in place after adding new source files
>   to it. The tool compiles only the new
>   or changed files unless you include
>   the -c option.

Comment: in then end I added a post build command of: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v / -p "$(ProjectDir)\"