# ASP.net Web Forms, get aspx/view errors at compile time?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms, build-process, resharper

I know this can be done with mvc2, but is there any way for visual studio(2010)/resharper(6) to check for errors on aspx pages at compile time and halt the build? Resharper can detect the errors just fine, so it seems like there should be a way to integrate a check of all the aspx pages in to the build process.

Any tips?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes you can. The following steps will cause .aspx files to be compiled as part of a normal builk invoked by the IDE, no Resharper plugin required.

- Unload your web app (right click on the project and select ‘Unload Project’)
- Open the .csproj file in a text editor (right click on the project and select ‘Edit myProjectName.csproj’)
- At the bottom of the file find the comment which says ‘To modify your build process…’ and insert the following after that comment:

`<Target Name="AfterBuild"><AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(ProjectDir)" /></Target>`

Source - [Compile Aspx pages at compile time using the AspNetCompiler build task](http://eliasbland.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/compile-aspx-pages-at-compile-time-using-the-aspnetcompiler-build-task/)

Comment: This highlighted a weird dependency issue, so I cant confirm if its working yet. Looks promising though, will post a status update in a bit

Comment: <Target Name="AfterBuild">
 <AspNetCompiler  VirtualPath="temp"  PhysicalPath="$(ProjectDir)" />
 </Target>

Comment: Hi Justin and @DanaBenson this step certainly highlight the errors, but it still says "Rebuild all successfull", may be cause it's a post-compile step... so, I assume there is nothing to do it on-compilation, right???

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to do this at compile time because compiling views is slow...

What you really want to do is have a NAnt (or something else) task that will XML poke this target into your web .csproj file prior to compiling the source code on your CI server.

This way your developers don't have to put up with the time wasting of the AspNetCompiler every time they do CTRL+SHIFT+B locally in Visual Studio, but you can still alert people to views with syntax errors on the CI server by failing the CI build.

Update: Here is a method that will run your view build outside of Visual Studio, but still on your local PC :)

http://www.luisrocha.net/2011/10/avoiding-mvcbuildviews-build-time.html

Comment: While you're correct in that (especially on larger projects) this slows a build down, it would be nice to be able to somehow inline this so that developers pushing larger changesets TO a CI server can check before they're sent to ensure it builds. Not every time, just in certain instances - so it's disabled by default.

Comment: 1) Use a CI system that allows for personal builds (e.g. TeamCity) 2) Have a batch/cmd/powershell file that pokes MvcBuildViews=true and runs the integration tests locally that your devs can use to test the views before they check in 3) let the CI environment catch this for you, since it won't happen that often.

Comment: Not sure if MvcBuildViews is a valid option for WebForms, is it? I'm aware of it and utilize that on my projects that are on the MVC framework, but the one I had in mind is not.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628799/is-there-an-equivalent-to-mvcbuildviews-for-webforms

Comment: The last place I worked use the solution proposed by @Mattygabe , but did it conditionally on the Configuration so that if you built in Release mode you could check it locally, but the default Debug didn't impact compile time.  The CI build just always built the Release bits.