# Is it possible to precompile an ASP.NET Web Forms Project on a build server?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

ASP.NET Web Forms apps have a large startup cost on the first request as they need to compile the views code (.ascx, .aspx, etc).  We have to deploy these projects to several servers, which requires priming each of them so that the first users to hit certain areas of the site don't have a bad response time.  Today this is a manual process, and we're making it automated by running `aspnet_compiler`.

Is is possible to run `aspnet_compiler` on the build server and deploy its output so that we do not have to run it on each web server we're deploying to?

**Bonus Question:** When we specify a target directory with the `targetdir` option in `aspnet_compiler`, how does IIS know where to look for the compiled files?  i.e. Where is that information stored?

The project in question is a Web Application project (not a Web Site project).

Comment: What about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6613174/185123?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in Visual Studio's Publish dialogue which may be what you want.

[image: Precompile Option]

I've not used it to see if it actually has the effect you want, but there's several options in **Configure** for it. You may be able to do what you want with that.

(P.S.: This is an ASP.NET Web Forms Project as well, in VB.NET. Though the language is irrelevant.)

Also, according to [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227976(v=vs.100).aspx) you can add the `-u` and `-v` switches to the `aspnet_compiler` to get it to precompile the views for updating.

You may also want to look at [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863(v=vs.140).aspx) as well, as it describes a scenario similar to yours. Especially the **Compiling an Application for Deployment** section, which states:

> You compile an application for deployment (compilation to a target location) by specifying the targetDir parameter. The targetDir can be the final location for the Web application, **or the compiled application can be further deployed**.

Essentially, you might be able to run this command on your build server, and then distribute your binaries as needed.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't fix my issue. We run our builds on a build server. I want the output from that build server to be a deployable artifact with views precompiled.

Comment: @JoshKodroff What build server do you use? How is it setup?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Either it's possible to deploy a precompiled binary to another server or you have to run `aspnet_compiler` on the deploy target.

Comment: @JoshKodroff You'll always have to run `aspnet_compiler` somewhere, as that is the only way to compile the views and such. You can probably have the build server run it in this case and deploy the compiled views as well.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, but the "probably" part is what I need a definitive answer for.

Comment: @JoshKodroff You won't know if you don't try it. I can tell you whether or not it works in my environment, but if yours is different, all bets are off. I recommend you try it first on a local/development machine setup the same way as your other ones.

Comment: Yes, but the point of my question is whether you can precompile on one machine and port that precompiled dll to another machine.

Comment: @JoshKodroff Well, give it a whirl man. Precompile it on your dev PC, and then move the generated binaries to another machine with IIS on it. I can try it later, and tell you what I find, but that wouldn't be until 8-9 EDT tonight.